# The number of topics to use for Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

We are planning integration with high load requirements (up to 100 000 messages per second) using Apache Kafka.
In this case there will be about 100 services (message types).

We consider 2 options:

- Option 1. The common pair of topics (REQ-queries, RESP-answers) for
  all calls.
- Option 2. A separate pair of topics (REQ-queries,
  RESP-answers) for each service(message type).

Which option do you recommend? Is there any difference in these options, for example, from a performance point of view?

Comment: Generally option 1 is more preferred over 2nd as  partition it by message type, this will give you locality and order by message type. In other words you get a stronger ordering guarantee than you would if you had one topic per user and it is vastly more efficient.

Comment: Also keep in my mind that zookeeper keeps one znode per partition which may gets exhausted by more number of partitions